# How can I work with .LIST file using Javascript or PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, list

I have a `.list` file that I would like to use as an array either with JS or PHP. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: how does the contents of the file look like?

Comment: Every row is like this:
`"#1 Single" (2006)     Los Angeles, California, USA`

The spaces in between are not constant across all the rows. The first column is a movie/music title and the second column is some location information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quick Solution**

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('path/to/your/file.list', 'r');
$array = array();
while( ! feof($fp))
{
    $array[] = fgets($fp, 1024);
}
fclose($fp);

print_r($array);
?>
```

This will create an array with each entry being one line of your .list file.

**Further Reading**

If you want more information, such as error handling, you can check out [this php manual page on fgets()](http://php.net/fgets) it has code examples on there.

You may also be interested in [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/fgetcsv) which also has code examples

Comment: That code snippet worked very well. It was exactly what I was looking for. Of course, there is still the matter of further dividing each line as columns but at least now I have an array I can work with. Thanks.